# Explanation on python __iter__ and next() printing outputs

Tags: python, class, iterator, generator, theory

I've learnt from the official documentation of python 2.7.8 how to work with iterators and generators. I've got a question related on a curiosity.

```
it = iter("abcde")
print it
>>> <iterator object at 0x7ff4c2b3bad0>

class example1():
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.index = len(word)
    def __iter__(self):
        for x in range(self.index - 1, -1, -1):
            yield self.word[x]

a = example1("altalena")
print iter(a)
>>> <generator object __iter__ at 0x7f24712000a0>
```

In the above examples, when I print the iterators, i read "generator","iterator" object and the hexadecimal ID. Why I can't do the same with the following code?

```
class example2():
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.index = len(word)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next (self):
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.word[self.index]
a = example2()
print iter(a)
>>> <__main__.example2 instance at 0x7f89ee2de440>
```

I think it is caused by "return self" in **iter**, that leads to the class instance, but i don't know the solution to get a more right output. It may be useless but I don't know why it is an how to avoid it.

Comment: If you want to change what `print` does to your instance, you have to play with `__repr__` and/or `__str__`

Comment: Please, try to respect PEP8 in the future

Comment: So I have made no mistakes, right? I've just to create the behaviour that I like, in order to obtain a returning string with the proper style. I've made this a few times to solve other problems related to im_data and im_self... but how can i obtain the memory ID of the iterator and not of the class instance?

Comment: what says PEP8? i'm reading python doc from the beginning section "tutorial", although in the past i've learned python in general, now i want to study all the documentation and so i'm still learning.

Comment: Lazy solution: make `print iter(a)` show whatever you want by defining `example2`'s `__str__` method, returning the desired string. Now it will no longer show `<main.example2 instance...`

Comment: [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is a coding style guide for Python, designed for the Python standard library, but everyone uses it.

Comment: I'll surely study PEP8, thank you very much for your advice, it's good for me to expand my knowledge. Sorry if I make mistakes sometimes, I'm italian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generators are a type of iterator. Your `example1` class is returning a generator because you used `yield` in the `__iter__`; it is a *separate iterator object*, returned from `__iter__`. This makes your `example1` class *iterable*, not an iterator itself.

In your second example your class `__iter__` returns `self`. It is not just iterable, it is its own *iterator*. Because it is returning `self`, *there is no separate object here*.

Python makes an explicit distinction between *iterable* and *iterator*. An *iterable* can *potentially* be iterated over. An *iterator* does the actual work when iterating. By using `iter()` you ask Python to produce an *iterator* for a given *iterable*.

This is why `iter(stringobject)` returns a new object; you have produced an *iterator* from the *iterable* string.

You need this distinction because the process of iterating requires something that keeps state; namely *where in the process are we now*. An *iterator* is the object that keeps track of that, so that each time you call the `.next()` method on the iterator, you get the next value, or `StopIteration` is raised if there is no next value to produce anymore.

So in your example, the string and `example1` are both just *iterable*, and calling `iter()` on them produced a new separate *iterator*.

However, your `example2` is it's **own** *iterator*. Calling `iter()` on it does not produce a separate object. You cannot create separate *iterators* from something that *already* is an *iterator*.

If you want to produce a new independent *iterator* for your `example2` class, you need to return a distinct, separate object from `__iter__`:

```
class ExampleIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source
        self.position = len(source)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.position <= 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.position -= 1
        return self.source[self.position]

class Example2():
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word

    def __iter__(self):
        return ExampleIterator(self)
```

Here `Example2` is just a *iterable* again, not an *iterator*. The `__iter__` method returns a new, distinct `ExampleIterator()` instance, and it is responsible for keeping track of the iteration state.

Comment: ok so it's already an iterator. so why i get "instance" instead of "iterator"? simply because it is an object obtained by instantation of a class?

Comment: You are looking at the default `__repr__` representation string for custom classes. If you want it to say something different, implement your own `__repr__` method.

Comment: If you did *not* call `iter()` on the object it would also use the same representation string.

Comment: correct me if i'm saying something wrong: since example2 in my example is already iterator & iterable, calling the function iter(example2) doesn't return any effect, and so it is useless.

Comment: @PatrickRoncagliolo: it is not useless. The iterator for an iterator is the object itself, but code that always uses `iter()` to support iterables doesn't have to know about this detail.

Comment: @PatrickRoncagliolo: it is 'useless' in that `int(1)` is useless; you want to make *sure* something is an integer, but passing something that is already an integer is harmless. This is useful behaviour.

Comment: so it is useful because using iter() and passing to it as argoument an iterable or an iterator provides always iterators, and supports as "input argouments" both types, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have a problem, you just don't understand what happens here.

In general, `iter(object)` returns an iterator for this iterable object.

This is obtained either via calling `__iter__()` or, if that doesn't exist, by providing a wrapper object which calls `__getitem__()` until it is exhausted (raises `IndexError`).

The object returned by `__iter__()` can either be the iterable itself (like in your 2nd example) or something else. Especially, it can be a generator object if you make `__iter__()` a generator function as you do in your 1st example.

The iteration itself happens with the iterator object and its `next()` resp. `__next__()` method.